# Persist List of Strings with ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

So I have an Entity class that holds a property with @ElementCollection annotation for a List of Strings. The point is of course to persists/retrieve list of strings.

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> listOfThings;
```

Based on this definition, Hibernate has created new db table, however when I assign a value to listOfThings:

```
record.setListOfThings(listOfStrings);
```

I can see there is an exception:

```
method threw 'org.hibernate.lazyinitializationexception' exception. cannot evaluate tostring() ...
```

So, after learning that I need actually to annotate `listOfThings` with EAGER loading:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<String> listOfThings;
```

I have started getting new error message:

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: collections cannot be fetched by a stateless org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.initializeCollection(StatelessSessionImpl.java:299)
```

So either way, storing a list of strings doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your collection, e.g:

```
private List<String> listOfThings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Worked fine to me.